# bash debugging using set -u

Tags: linux, debugging, bash, set, environment-variables

I have a bash ***sourcedbash.sh***  sourced in another bash main code ***main.sh***.
Running ***main.sh*** with the "*set -u*" option, I'm getting an error than I can't figure out :

```
Error /sourced_bash.sh : line xx : variable without link
```

***main.sh***

```
. sourced_bash.sh
my_function $foomain 1
```

***sourcedbash.sh***

```
function my_function(){
   local foo=$1
   local bar=$2
   if [[ 1 -eq $bar ]];then # <= this is LINE xx generating the error
        # ... dothis
        return 1
   elif [[ 0 -eq $bar ]];then
        # ... dothat
        return 0
   fi
}
```

Looked into the man pages and reading "my friend" w/o a frank success.

I'd need to understand why "*set -u*" implies the ***main.sh*** program aborption and how to get rid of this error (Debian Lenny).

Thx in advance

Comment: foomain are actually 5 strings used differently depending on the bar case in "dothis" or "dothat", but the error points out the test line on "bar".

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing string comparison, you need to use quotes and ==. Try changing to:

```
   if [[ "1" == "$bar" ]] || [[ "true" == "$bar" ]];then
```

**Update:**

What is `$foomain`? Has it been set?

`set -u` makes Bash check whether you have initialised all your variables. If you haven't, Bash will throw an error about unbound variables.

Comment: Thx - this is a transcription error, actually I'm not using strings.

Comment: Thx, I edited the question as using strings is not the point I guess.

Comment: @hornetbzz have you initialised `$foomain`?

Comment: yes $foomain is initialized and actually defined as a set of 4 preset data and the 5th (table names) coming from a FOR loop, as the goal is to check mysql connection using ssh, so with consistent parameters.